# Angular.js - Using $location.search without enabling routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building an application that uses Angular.js but doesn't use Angular's routing system (It's a bit of a convoluted setup really). I am trying to use `$location.search()` to retrieve all query parameters (and eventually set them), but when I haven't called `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`, it returns an empty object.

If I have called `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`, Angular takes over all of the routing, and none of my links work. Is there a way to use `$location.search` without HTML5 mode, or using HTML5 mode without it taking over all of my anchors?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I should probably also mention that I need `$location.search` for the object and array serialisation, so I can't just use `window.location.search`, unless I want to write a parser.

Comment: have you tried to use `$routeParams` instead?

Comment: I have and it has the same issue. According to the docs, it internally calls `$location.search` anyway.